# Change the status bar and navigation bar color?

Tags: android, colors, uinavigationbar, root, statusbar

I wanted to know if there's a way to change the status bar background color as well as the icons on Android phones. Will changing the background and button color of the navigation bar also works?(e.g. in Nexus devices or others with software buttons only)
I wanted to develop an app which changes these colors so it fits the apps UI(like on the iOS, or on the PanaroidAndroid ROM). There should be some workaround, at least with root permission(?)

HINT: With navigation bar I mean the bar at the bottom of the screen that displays the soft keys, NOT to be confused with the android action-bar!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799097/overlay-action-bar-with-a-translucent-status-bar