# Overlay action bar with a translucent status bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to achieve the effect shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QHkv-bSlds&t=15m48s by Nick and the boys. I can get the action bar to be overlayed, but cannot figure out how to extend this to the status bar. I would also like to know how they managed the transparent black background behind the navigation bar (but this isn't as crucial).

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated as I currently have no idea how this is done (and am starting to worry it may just be an image rather than an actual implementation).

Edit: i know how to make the bars fully transparent (thats the easy part)! I dont know how to extend the actionbar background to appear behind the now transluscent status bar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same question and found this library: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Have a look at line 300 in:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint/blob/master/library/src/com/readystatesoftware/systembartint/SystemBarTintManager.java

`setupStatusBarView()` Adds a view to the window's decor. This allows you to later set a color/drawable to this view.

If using the **SystemBarTint** library, the following will allow you to force the status bar to a specified color, which you can then match to your action bar's background:

```
SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(Color.parseColor("#DD000000"));
```

In this case you would set your action bar's background to: **#DD000000**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tanner, I ended up doing something very similar, so will accept your answer for future readers.

Comment: I tried using this library,actually i want to change color of status bar. But it is not changing color.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [Android 4.4 APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI):

> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new themes, [Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor](http://Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor) and [Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor](http://Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor). By enabling translucent system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so you must also enable [fitsSystemWindows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fitsSystemWindows) for the portion of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars.
>
> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the parent theme or include the [windowTranslucentNavigation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentNavigation) and [windowTranslucentStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus) style properties in your theme.

In your case (where you want the ActionBar), the second option - including the two new properties into your theme - will give you a translucent Navigation and Status bar.

Comment: this makes the status bar transparent but doesn't extend the actionbar background behind it, so the status bar has a gradient from black to fully  transparent and then the action bar starts.

Comment: @krishan711 - yes, it is transparent to the background of your Activity and not tied to the Action Bar color at all, hence why the video has the ActionBar have the same translucent background as the status bar (so they appear to be the same element) and why the included themes are `NoActionBar` themes (as usually you wouldn't want the background of your Activity above the ActionBar).

Comment: okay, but there is no api to set the background of the status bar? also you seem to contradict yourself..how can i have a background on the actionbar and also use NoActionBar (or am i misunderstanding?). I am currently using the windowTranslucentStatus flag to achieve the transparent status bar.

Comment: @krishan711 - two things:
1) No API to set the background of the status bar - you either get the Activity background over a translucent status bar or the default solid status bar
2) Given 1), the only option for matching the ActionBar background to the status bar is to make the ActionBar also translucent.

Comment: Yes, i understand this, but the transparent status bar fades from black (at the top) to completely transparent (at the bottom). Making the actionbar translucent doesn't make the status bar transluscent at the bottom. So what i get is | black -> transparent | translucent |. In case you are suggestiong making the actionbar TRANSPARENT, that works  but isn't what i want (i want a black transluscent background like in the videdo).

Comment: @krishan711 - so it is the black->transparent part that you want to remove? They do mention at [17:00](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6QHkv-bSlds#t=1020) in the video that the black->transparent will always be there.

Comment: No, I dont want to remove it. I want the effect shown in the video at the time 15m 48s; that is - the black -> transparent seems to be above (z index not y position) a translucent black layer that is the same color as the actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

They are using the new [Translucent system bars](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#TranslucentBars) feature (on Android 4.4 and up).

> Translucent system bars
>
> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new
>   themes, Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor and
>   Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor. By enabling translucent
>   system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so
>   you must also enable fitsSystemWindows for the portion of your layout
>   that should not be covered by the system bars.
>
> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the
>   parent theme or include the windowTranslucentNavigation and
>   windowTranslucentStatus style properties in your theme.

Comment: this does not do what i want (out of the box). Please see my comment to @ianhanniballake